# How fix error with PHP login that ask two times for username and password

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

When I want to login with this codes in first time I connect to internet, I enter the username and password and push submit and the page get refresh and ask me again for username and password and after enter the username and password for second time the login done!

My code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include ('connect-db.php');

    $escapedName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $escapedPW = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $saltQuery = "select salt from user where username = '$escapedName';";
    $result = mysql_query($saltQuery);

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $salt = $row['salt'];

    $pass=md5($escapedPW);
    $password_pro= $pass . $salt;

    $query = mysql_query("select * from user where username = '$escapedName' and password = '$password_pro'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);

    if($row){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username'] = $escapedName;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
        $_SESSION['type'] = $row['user_type'];
        $_SESSION['user_id']= $row['user_id'];
        $user_id=$row['user_id'];

        header('location: panel.php?user_id=$user_id');
    }
```

Comment: `$user_id` is not a variable in single quotes... concatenate it or use double quotes. Also you dont need 2 queries and md5 is out of date you should use a newer hashing method.

Comment: this code shouldn't be used and for so many reasons

Comment: `mysql.*` functions have been deprecated almost a century ago...

Comment: Have you tried to debug the variable $row ? You should always start "session_start" at the beginning of your code otherwise it wont retrieve the data.

Comment: thanks max it solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `session_start();` at top of the  page  and also check your form tag's attributes